# How can I track object lifetime in C++11 lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

Sometimes, we know nothing about lifetime of lambda that captures an object state (e.g. return it from object, register it as a callback without ability to unsubscribe etc.). How to make sure that the lambda won't access already destroyed object on invocation?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(const std::string& i_name) : name(i_name) {}

    std::function<void()> GetPrinter() {
        return [this]() {
            std::cout << name << std::endl;
        };
    }

    std::string name;
};

int main() {
    std::function<void()> f;

    {
        auto foo = std::make_shared<Foo>("OK");
        f = foo->GetPrinter();
    }

    auto foo = std::make_shared<Foo>("WRONG");

    f();

    return 0;
}
```

This program prints "WRONG" instead of "OK" (http://ideone.com/Srp7RC) just by coincidence (it seems it just reused the same memory for the second `Foo` object). Anyway, this is a wrong program. First `Foo` object is already dead when we execute `f`.

Comment: The code is not accepted by [_clang_](http://rextester.com/RGHTRH51840)

Comment: @P0W hmm, maybe clang is out of date? I guess clang-3.3 should compile this (can't check right now).

Comment: Yes it does [compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5db723cce74bc805) on latest one, thanks !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Extend object lifetime

Lambdas can capture shared pointers to `this`, so an object won't die while at least one lambda exists.

```
class Foo : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo> {
public:
    Foo(const std::string& i_name) : name(i_name) {}

    std::function<void()> GetPrinter() {
        std::shared_ptr<Foo> that = shared_from_this();

        return [that]() {
            std::cout << that->name << std::endl;
        };
    }

    std::string name;
};
```

http://ideone.com/Ucm2p8

Usually, it is not a good solution, as object lifetime is extended in very implicit manner here. It is very easy way of producing circular references between objects.

### Track object lifetime

Lambdas can track captured object lifetime and use the object only if it is still alive.

```
class Foo : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo> {
public:
    Foo(const std::string& i_name) : name(i_name) {}

    std::function<void()> GetPrinter() {
        std::weak_ptr<Foo> weak_this = shared_from_this();

        return [weak_this]() {
            auto that = weak_this.lock();
            if (!that) {
                std::cout << "The object is already dead" << std::endl;
                return;
            }

            std::cout << that->name << std::endl;
        };
    }

    std::string name;
};
```

http://ideone.com/Wi6O11

### Track object lifetime without shared pointers

As *hvd* [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27721978/194635), we can't always be sure that an object is managed by `shared_ptr`. In such case, I would suggest using the following `lifetime_tracker`. It is self-contained and doesn't affect the way you manage object lifetime.

```
struct lifetime_tracker
{
private:
    struct shared_state
    {
        std::uint32_t count : 31;
        std::uint32_t dead  : 1;
    };

public:
    struct monitor
    {
        monitor() : state(nullptr) {}

        monitor(shared_state *i_state) : state(i_state) {
            if (state)
                ++state->count;
        }

        monitor(const monitor& t) : state(t.state) {
            if (state)
                ++state->count;
        }

        monitor& operator=(monitor t) {
            std::swap(state, t.state);
            return *this;
        }

        ~monitor() {
            if (state) {
                --state->count;
                if (state->count == 0 && state->dead)
                    delete state;
            }
        }

        bool alive() const {
            return state && !state->dead;
        }

    private:
        shared_state *state;
    };

public:
    lifetime_tracker() : state(new shared_state()) {}
    lifetime_tracker(const lifetime_tracker&) : state(new shared_state()) {}
    lifetime_tracker& operator=(const lifetime_tracker& t) { return *this; }

    ~lifetime_tracker() {
        if (state->count == 0)
            delete state;
        else
            state->dead = 1;
    }

    monitor get_monitor() const {
        return monitor(state);
    }

private:
    shared_state *state;
};
```

Example of usage

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(const std::string& i_name) : name(i_name) {}

    std::function<void()> GetPrinter() {
        auto monitor = tracker.get_monitor();

        return [this, monitor]() {
            if (!monitor.alive()) {
                std::cout << "The object is already dead" << std::endl;
                return;
            }

            std::cout << this->name << std::endl;
        };
    }

private:
    lifetime_tracker tracker;

    std::string name;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Stas's answer is good when you can be certain that objects are managed by a `shared_ptr`, but that isn't always possible. What you can always do, though, is track the lifetime of objects, and add an assertion in your lambda.

```
void ignore(void *) { }

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(const std::string& i_name) : name(i_name) {}
    Foo(const Foo& other) : name(other.name) {}
    Foo(Foo&& other) : name(std::move(other.name)) {}
    Foo& operator=(Foo other) { swap(*this, other); return *this; }
    friend void swap(Foo& a, Foo& b) { using std::swap; swap(a.name, b.name); }

    std::function<void()> GetPrinter() {
        std::weak_ptr<void> monitor = this->monitor;

        return [=]() {
            assert (!monitor.expired());
            std::cout << name << std::endl;
        };
    }

    std::string name;

private:
    std::shared_ptr<void> monitor{this, ignore};
};
```

In the constructor, the shared pointer `monitor` is not explicitly initialised, but set up through its initialiser to point to `this`, and to do nothing once the pointer's lifetime expires. The idea isn't to make `shared_ptr` responsible for freeing the object, the idea is only to let `shared_ptr` pass along information on the object's lifetime.

Prior to the creation of your lambda, you can construct a `weak_ptr` which tracks the associated `shared_ptr`. If the object has been destroyed, then its `monitor` member will necessarily also have been destroyed, and that becomes visible through the `expired()` function.

Comment: Yes, good idea. But you need to define copy-constructor. Now, it will behave incorrectly if you copy Foo object.

Comment: @Stas Right, thanks for pointing that out. And a move constructor and assignment operator, too.