# C++ Ownership without heap allocation

Tags: c++, heap-memory

`std::shared_ptr` keeps the pointed object alive by allocating it on the heap, thus ensuring its creation and destruction are done only when appropriate. However, if I wanted to simply monitor the object lifetime - without the need to extend it based on the number of references to it - is there a way I could *without needing a heap allocation*?

I would essentially like `std::weak_ptr` semantics without the need for the object to be heap allocated. Is it possible to do this in C++?

Comment: Yes it's possible. You can write an `Allocator<T>` class and placement `new()` operator, to implement your own memory allocation strategy.

Comment: Take a look at this answer by Stas
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27721053/999986

Comment: @Nir Note that all of Stas's solutions still perform heap allocation. You can eliminate the heap allocation by making the observer provide the state.

Comment: `However, if I wanted to simply monitor the object lifetime - without the need to extend it based on the number of references to it`  it is not fully clear to me what you want to achieve, or what you require exactly. If you don’t need reference counting, and the possibility to move the ownership, then why do you need a pointer at all? (`Obj obj;` also expresses ownership.)

Comment: @t.niese The idea is that they have a reference to some object they don't own (`obj`) and want to create some sort of "lifetime tracker" object: `lifetime_tracker tracker(obj);` so they can later ask `tracker.is_alive` which is `true` if `obj` has not yet destructed. (If `obj` were a `shared_ptr`, you could use `weak_ptr` as your lifetime tracker.) You can solve this by having `obj` maintain a list of active lifetime trackers, and its destructor sets `tracker.is_alive = false` on each one.

Comment: Yep, Raymond Chen got it exactly. Thanks for all the useful comments. (BTW, I love The Old New Thing!) However, if you do have a list of all lifetime trackers, how do you make sure that your lifetime trackers are alive so that you can set their internal flag? Isn't this a circular dependency?

Comment: @super The lifetime tracker's destructor removes itself from the list (if the object is still alive). That was sort of implied by saying that the object keeps a list of **active** lifetime trackers. If a tracker is no longer active, then it comes off the list.